# jQuery menue parent child child

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Okay so I have a jQuery menu on this page [here.](http://wptemp.site90.net)

When you click on a parent (Bureau or Projecten) the child menue stays open at all the times even if you go: parent -> child -> child.

This does not work on: Bureau -> Publicaties -> "child"
The menue closes.

I dont understand since I covered both "parent categories" (current-menu-item.parent and current-portfolio-ancestor) in the jQuery?

Any ideas?

```
$('.current-menu-item').parent('.sub-menu').css('visibility', 'visible');
$('.current-menu-item.parent, .current-portfolio-ancestor').find('.sub-menu').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

The whole jQuery code [here](http://wptemp.site90.net/wp-content/themes/mulders-vandenberk/js/script.js?ver=3.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `http://wptemp.site90.net/portfolio/publicatie-test-b/`, this line doesn't have any of CSS classes (`.current-menu-item` for e.g.) you use in the `script.js`:

```
<li id="menu-item-102" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page parent menu-item-102">
```

As a result, visibility remains hidden.

Comment: So i need to change this in the CSS? Sorry if I'm a bit slow

Comment: I don't think so. The question is how come on this particular page, the CSS classes `.current-menu-item.parent, .current-portfolio-ancestor` are not being assigned to `<li id="menu-item-102">`. As you mentioned, it's working on other pages..

Comment: Well, 
Projecten=WP category. And so are the children there.
Where's in 
Bureau=WP Pages, except Publicaties which is a WP category. Could that be it?

Comment: That was the problem. Don't know why i couldn't see it before. Just added:
$('.current-portfolio-ancestor').parent('.sub-menu').css('visibility', 'visible');

Answer (score 0):

replace your two lines with

```
$('.current-menu-parent').parent().css('visibility', 'visible');
```

Comment: If i would do that then the sub menues will not stay open.